# Alchemy.js simple example not working

Tags: alchemy.js

I'm trying to implement this example in order to become familiar with Alchemy.js. http://graphalchemist.github.io/Alchemy/#/examples how can I fix this to make it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alchemy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/alchemy.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="alchemy" id="alchemy"></div>

<script src="bower_components/alchemy.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alchemy.begin({dataSource: "charlize.json"});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Check out my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43722137/cant-render-a-simple-html-page-example basically HREF and SRC are out-dated

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using the wrong library, try with this:

(Can you try including the vendor script first and then the alchmey script.)

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alchemyjs/0.4.2/alchemy.min.js"></script>
```